# Is it possible to use the Hive database file used in Android in the Web App?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Click a button on Android or the web to upload the Hive file to the server. Then, in another operating system, download the Hive file that exists on the server and use it.

Android Hive File -> Use Web

Web Hive File -> Use Android

Is this possible?

My explanation may seem complicated. If you do not understand, please leave a comment and I will try to explain in more detail.

Comment: What do you want to do with such feature? Yes Hive helps with storing data locally. But not for you to come and transfer the Data Store. Remember it's binary encrypted. If you need such Android/Web communication, you should use a backend. (You should already be using that to transfer the files if you achieve it in the first place)

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude Due to my lack of experience, I could not predict the problem. I learned a lot from this opportunity. Thanks for leaving a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna just to have your `Hive` database saved on your backed, then consider getting it as a List:

```
final dataThatWillBeSent = box.values.toList();
```

Then pass that `dataThatWillBeSent` in  your backend simply, you can make observables for it.

I couldn't say that's not possible to make transfers with the `.hive` files, but there is no point of it when you can simply send your data as regular data structures like `List`, `Map<String, dynamix>`.

the `Hive` saves the data in the device by encrypting it with binaries, so even if you managed to make transfers with it, you need to have decrypters also for it.